# translation keras to pytorch - mismatching in CNN layer

Tags: python, keras, pytorch, conv-neural-network, bioinformatics

I am trying to reproduce the [code](https://github.com/NAMlab/DeepCRE/blob/main/src/python/train_low_high_expressed_multi_species_models.py) of keras to pytorch. However I am struggling to reproduce the result.

code from keras :

```
def build_network(x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val, specie_name, val_chrom):
backend.clear_session()
model = Sequential([
    # Conv Block 1
    Conv1D(64, kernel_size=8, activation='relu', padding='same',
           input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])),
    Conv1D(64, kernel_size=8, activation='relu', padding='same'),
    MaxPool1D(8, padding='same'),
    Dropout(0.25),

    # Conv Block 2
    Conv1D(128, kernel_size=8, activation='relu', padding='same'),
    Conv1D(128, kernel_size=8, activation='relu', padding='same'),
    MaxPool1D(8, padding='same'),
    Dropout(0.25),

    # Conv Block 3
    Conv1D(64, kernel_size=8, activation='relu', padding='same'),
    Conv1D(64, kernel_size=8, activation='relu', padding='same'),
    MaxPool1D(8, padding='same'),
    Dropout(0.25),

    # Fully connected Block
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.25),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

])
```

code from pytorch :

```
from typing import List
class DNA_CNN_test2(nn.Module): # deepcre model  
    def __init__(self,
                 seq_len: int =1000,
                 kernel_size: int = 8,
                 p = 0.25): # drop out value 
        super().__init__()
        self.seq_len = seq_len
        # CNN module
        self.conv_net = nn.Sequential()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(4,64,kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same'),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv1d(64,64,kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same'),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=8),
            nn.Dropout(p),
            nn.Conv1d(64,128,kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same'),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv1d(128,128,kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same'),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=8),
            nn.Dropout(p),
            nn.Conv1d(128,64,kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same'),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv1d(64,64,kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same'),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=8),
            nn.Dropout(p),
            nn.Flatten(),
        
            nn.Linear(64, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(p),
            nn.Linear(128, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, 1)
        )#.to(device)
         
    def forward(self, xb: torch.Tensor):
        """Forward pass."""
        xb = xb.permute(0, 2, 1) 
        out = self.conv_net(xb)
        return out
```

I am following all the order of the original code however the code give me an error, which I can locate. Here I am using 4096 batch size. My input is one hot encoded DNA sequence (1000bp) and its  corresponding transcript value (numeric). What have I missed?

```
The size of tensor a (4) must match the size of tensor b (4096) at non-singleton dimension 1
```