# pytorch reshape tensor - broadcasting

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tensor

I am trying to reshape my tensor for CNN model. Original [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76797993/translation-keras-to-pytorch-mismatching-in-cnn-layer) is posted, however I am struggling with reshaping my tensor. I have tried the `[unsquenze][2]()` function to reformat the input and the output.

Here the 4096 is the batch size, 4 is the channel, 1000 is the sequence length. My question will be how can I unsquenze the 3d matrix to 2d for suitable input or do i need to `squenze()` them instead of `unsquenze()`

```
 UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([4096, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([4096, 4, 1000])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
```